# VIM Adventures in level 8 - "Today you are You,"

Tags: vim-adventures

In Vim Adventures, level 8 (figure below):

How can I get to the first "Y" character on the other island?

[image]

[image: possible keys]

Comment: Can you add the actual question to the body so that people know exactly what you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer my own question:

- got the "n" key from the blue door (the puzzle before)
- stood at "You" from the puzzle at the right
- taped * or #
- went inside the puzzle in question
- used "n" key

Comment: I'd been trying to jump from block of text to block of text using the * or the # - kept cycling through the block I was in. Didn't realize that one hint was trying to tell me I could "save my search". Thanks for ansewring the question. :) This is such a fun game and I'm learning a ton about VIM.